# How to add an addon domain to cpanel with same name but different tld?

Tags: hosting, cpanel, addon-domain

I have a cpanel account with option for unlimited add-on domains. I have added a domain, say, `example.org`. For this, cpanel has also created a sub-domain for main hosting domain `example.main-domain.com`.

Now I have purchased another domain `example.com`. When I try to add it through addon domains option, cpanel gives an error that subdomain `example.main-domain.com` already exists.

Is there a way to add the second domain in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the subdomain is determined by the `Subdomain or FTP Username:` you set when you add the subdomain.

Cpanel auto-fills this field with the first part of the domain name but you can enter anything you like.

So when you go to add `example.com` Cpanel will auto-fill the `Subdomain or FTP Username:` to `example` and try to create the subdomain `example.main-domain.com` which already exists from when you added `example.org` in the same way so it will throw an error like

> (XID bqnr82) A DNS entry for the domain “example.main-domain.com” already exists.

Instead when you add `example.com` enter any unused value into the `Subdomain or FTP Username:` field, such as `exampledotcom` and the subdomain cpannel creates will be at

`exampledotcom.main-domain.com`

This is explained and discussed here

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/addon-domains-differing-only-in-tld-extension.249141/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the sub-domain name to example1 while adding the other domain example.com. So, that the next sub-domain will be example1.main-domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

When you create addon domain it also creates subdomain for the addon domain. Now you since create subdomain with name example already so when you attempt to add addon domain with name example.com it could not create subdomain example since it was already added. Just rename already created subdomain and attempt to add the server. It will fix the problem.