# set up addondomain getting "This website no longer exists or never existed."

Tags: cpanel, addon-domain

I setup an addondomain and I was able to create it following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753676/how-to-add-an-addon-domain-to-cpanel-with-same-name-but-different-tld/42978982). Now I wanted to access that addondomain using the name I used in the `Addon Domains` column. In this link the equivalent of the address I want to access is `exampledotcom.main-domain.com` but I am getting `"This website no longer exists or never existed."`

> I'm asking is it the problem of creating the `addondomain` or I'm just accessing the incorrect address

Answer (score 0):

```
exampledotcom.main-domain.com
```

Is a Subdomian.

```
another-domain.com
```

or `main-domain.com` would be

Would be an Addon Domain.